# Excel. как сделать авто изменение адреса ссылки по номеру из другой ячейки?

Tags: excel, excel-формулы

Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы в простой ссылке менялся адрес на число из другой ячейки
к примеру: ячейка содержит адрес **='Перечень'!C3** и мне надо сделать так чтобы **С** оставалось, а число **3** менялось в зависимости от числа в другой ячейке. Например в этой другой ячейке я ставлю **12** и адрес меняется на **='Перечень'!C12**

Answer (score 0):

Используйте для этого функцию `ДВССЫЛ`. К примеру `='Перечень'!C_` у вас находится в `A1`, а число, которое должно добавляться после `C` находится в ячейке `F1`, тогда в `A1` вам нужно прописать формулу:

```
=ДВССЫЛ("Перечень'!C"&F1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Недостатки функции `ДВССЫЛ`: текстовая (медленная), не работает со ссылками на закрытые книги. Но самая плохая ее характеристика - функция относится к небольшому числу летучих (пересчитывается не только при изменении входных данных, но и при любом изменении на листе). Бывает, что наличие единственной формулы с летучей функцией создает сильные тормоза при работе с листом, т.к. вызываются пересчеты большого количества формул на листе.

Если есть адекватная замена, `ДВССЫЛ` лучше не применять. А такая замена есть :)

```
=ИНДЕКС(Перечень!C:C;D1)
```

где `D1` - ячейка с номером строки

функция `ИНДЕКС`-  одна из самых быстрых.

Наличие в формуле динамической связи тоже вызовет пересчет листа, но только при открытии книги.

Answer (score 0):

Ещё есть функция `СМЕЩ()`:

```
=СМЕЩ(Перечень!$C$1;G11-1;0)
```

Первым аргументом ставим "якорь" в виде абсолютной ссылки на `Перечень!$C$1`.
Вторым - смещение на указанное кол-во строк в виде ссылки на G11 (например), где будет находиться номер строки. Отнимаем единицу, поскольку "якорь" уже на первой строке.
По столбцам изменений не планируется, поэтому третий аргумент 0.

Comment: СМЕЩ тоже в когорте летучих... Их всего 6-7 таких (СЕГОДНЯ(), СЛЧИС(), ТДАТА()...)

Answer (score 0):

Ребята, большое спасибо!
Очень помогли!
я в итоге использовал

```
=СМЕЩ('Перечень'!$C$1;'Заявление регистрация в РТН'!K15-1;0)
```